# React Native can't get response from localhost

Tags: react-native

i'm studying with React Native,
but i can't get response properly 
my fetch code is :

```
try {
     let response = fetch(
      "http://192.168.1.106/little_api/index.php",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json",
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
       body: JSON.stringify(data)
     }
    );


     console.log(response);
```

the response is :

[image]

the api response which i get from api when i try postman:

[image]

my php api is :
[image]

but my debugger console response is [image]

Comment: You have to use then operators to resolve the promise before you can have a response from fetch api

Comment: then(response => response.json()) like this ?

Comment: Please don't edit the title to mark your question as "solved". It's unnecessary and confusing for search results, which already highlight questions that have accepted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it using formdata:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('firstname', 'test');
```

If you do this, you don't have to use JSON.stringify:

```
fetch(
  "http://192.168.1.106/little_api/index.php",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
     "Accept": "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
   body: data
 }
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`fetch()` function return a promise, so you should resolve this promise using one of this 2 methods:

1/ Using `.then()`

```
fetch(
      "http://192.168.1.106/little_api/index.php",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json",
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
       body: JSON.stringify(data)
     }
   ).then(response => {
      console.log(response); //<- your response here
   }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error); //<-catch error
 });
```

2/ Using `async/await` syntax: you should add async keyword on the function where you call fetch

```
async getResponse(){
try {
   let response = fetch(
      "http://192.168.1.106/little_api/index.php",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json",
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
       body: JSON.stringify(data)
     }
    );
   console.log(response); //<- your response here
  } catch(e){
  console.log(e);<-catch error
  }
}
```

Comment: when i try first solve , the response is like this : https://prnt.sc/s70gyq

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the result when you used `.then()` @MustafaUYSAL

Comment: my code : https://prnt.sc/s70l32 the response : https://prnt.sc/s70lmj

Comment: @MustafaUYSAL try to delete this line in fetch options `body: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: The problem is clearly in this line `body: JSON.stringify(data)` because you send the body as string and you declared content-type as json in the header. Try to change it to `body: data`, if it doesn't work then try to change `Content-Type` in header. good luck

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is an asynchronous method, meaning it needs a `.then` callback. The data that immediatley comes from this then has a `json()` method attached to it to retrieve the actual data in a readable format.

```
  fetch("http://192.168.1.106/little_api/index.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
 }).then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
     console.log(data) // this should return your data
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

As Mahdi N said in his response, you can use the `async/await` syntax to retrieve the data without needing the nested callbacks.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input i got this error

Comment: That probably means the data that was returned was in an unreadable syntax (invalid JSON perhaps), or possibly you ran into a cross-origin (cors) error.

Comment: i use an extension which name is CORS it doesn't change on or off situations

Comment: Are you running on Android? First try to access http://192.168.1.106/little_api in the Chrome browser on the Android simulator or device. If that responds with a 200, then at least we know the device is able to contact the API. If it doesn't first try changing it to http://localhost/little_api and set up a reverse proxy (run `adb reverse tcp:80 tcp:80` in terminal) and then try again. Without more info about your setup I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: i'm running emulator and i try everything your suggestions. i access my api with postman.

Comment: The android emulator is a virtual machine so requesting localhost without the proxy will request the emulator localhost rather than your PC localhost, hence the need for the reverse proxy. I'm unsure if the IP address would work. I would ask a new question specifically focussed on this error, with the correct fetch syntax and usage of response.json() and include as many details as you can about both your dev environment and the emulator.

Having said that Mahdi's comment about removing `JSON.stringify` could be interesting.

Comment: when i use localhost i got this error : network request failed

Comment: Did you set up the reverse proxy? Run `adb reverse tcp:80 tcp:80` on your PC.

Comment: i did it. but nothing change

Comment: Ok well I'm unsure what else to suggest, sorry. Mahdi's comment about the JSON data in the request `body` being invalid could be a good lead.